# V-for="item in items". Use "item" in computed property

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code:

```
 <div v-for="list in getList" :key="list.id" class="tab">
        <h3>{{day(list)}}</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <img :src="require('../assets/day.svg')" alt="icon">
            <h4 class="description">{{list.weather[0].description}}</h4>
            <h4 class="max-temp">{{list.temp.max}}°C</h4>
            <h4 class="min-temp">{{list.temp.min}}°C</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my script:

```
day(arg) {
  var timestamp = arg.dt;
  var a = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  var days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  return days[a.getDay()];
},
```

How can I use list as argument? or is there anyway to pass "list" to my computed property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed properties do not take arguments but you can use a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html).

In your component definition

```js
filters: {
  weekday (timestamp) {
    let date = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
    return date.toLocaleDateString('en', {weekday: 'long'})
  }
}
```

and in your template

```html
<h3>{{ list.dt | weekday }}</h3>
```

A filter is preferable over say a method as methods run for every render cycle. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: I appreciate it. THANK YOU!

Comment: I have another question almost same how can I provide argument for attribute?  `<img :src="require('../assets/${icon(list.weather[0].icon | icon)}')" alt="icon"> `

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov I think that one might need its own question

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass arguments to a `computed property`. In VueJS, `computed properties` are derived from `data`.

If you want a thing like **passing arguments**, using `methods` instead of `computed properties`.

If you still want to use `computed properties`, you could derive a new list base on your list data, so that, It will have a new property which is the `day` property.

Comment: You can however pass arguments to a function returned by a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can pass arguments to a computed through an anonymous function

Others have mentioned that you cannot pass arguments to a `computed`, however you can do this pretty easily like this:

```
computed: {
  day() {
    return (list) => {
       // You now have access to the list argument you're trying to pass this computed
    }
  }
}
```

So then you can do something like this in your `template`:

```
<div v-for="list in getList" :key="list.id"> 
    <h3>{{day(list)}}</h3>
    <div class="details">
        <img :src="require('../assets/day.svg')" alt="icon">
        <h4 class="description">{{list.weather[0].description}}</h4>
        <h4 class="max-temp">{{list.temp.max}}°C</h4>
        <h4 class="min-temp">{{list.temp.min}}°C</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

With all of this being said this way of passing data to a `computed`  probably has it's use cases but most of the time you are probably better off using a `method` or a `filter`.